# python3 pattern program diagonal

Tags: python-3.x

[HOW IT SHOULD LOOK ALIKE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnhJk.jpg)

I want pattern to be like this, but I couldn't come up with the loops ((

```
rows = int(input("number of rows: "))
space = rows - 1
n = 5
for i in range(0, rows):
    for j in range(0, space):
        print("", end=" " * n)
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        print("*", end=" " * n)
    space = space - 1
    print()
space = 1
for i in range(rows - 1, 0, +1):
    for j in range(space, 0):
        print(" ", end=" ")
    for k in range(0, i - 1):
        print("*", end=" " * n)
    space = space + 1
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rows = int(input("number of rows: "))
width = int(input("width of your window: "))
space = 9 # space between stars
for i in range(rows):
    string = " " * (i % space)
    for j in range(width):
        if j % space == 0:
            string += "*"
        else:
            string += " "
    print(string)
```